# Removing part of string from field in MySQL view

Tags: mysql, view, trim

I am moving data from Oracle to MySQL, this data is relevant for several views.
In one View, part of a string needs to be stripped from the result in one field of the view - if it exists.

So 643726493.234 would be fine, but 643726493.234-tzuv would need to turn into 643726493.234.

(How) can I do that?

Comment: If -tzuv is common in all column values then you can use substr function

Comment: are there any requirements for the final string length?

Answer (score 0):

If the string have always the `-` charachter separating the two part you can use somethings like this

```
select substr(your_column, 1,  POSITION('@' IN your_column)-1) from your_table;
```

or for update

```
update your_table
set your_column = select substr(your_column, 1,  POSITION('@' IN your_column)-1);
```